# Spring Data Jpa multiple @EnableJpaRepositories with BootstrapMode.DEFERRED not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two `DataSource` beans in my Spring Boot application and also two `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` beans to configure Jpa and Hibernate for each of them. Thus I have 2 Spring Java Configs for them.

**After upgrading to** Spring Boot 2.1.0 I wanted to enable the new BootstrapMode `BootstrapMode.DEFERRED` for both configurations, but my application failed to startup in my StartupTests and also when starting the application in real.

**LOG**

```
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFERRED mode.
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 394ms. Found 14 repository interfaces.
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFERRED mode.
main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not register object
 [org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener@422ab737]
 under bean name
 'org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener':
 there is already object
 [org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener@3fe512d2]
 bound  at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.registerSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:120)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1027)
    at
 org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.potentiallyLazifyRepositories(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:226)
    at
 org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:177)
    at
 org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:85)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
```

I managed to get the application startup when only **ONE** `@EnableJpaRepositories` was set to `BootstrapMode.DEFERRED` and the other to `BootstrapMode.DEFAULT`.

**Question**

So my question is: Is it possible to configure multiple Spring Configurations with `@EnableJpaRepositories` and both `BootstrapMode` set to `DEFERRED`?

Comment: Please have a look inot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13833#issuecomment-412368711. May it will help you.

Comment: That ticket won't help I guess. I suspect this is an oversight in the implementation of the bootstrap mode. I suggest raising a ticket on the Spring Data JPA project.

Answer (score 0):

Setting BootstrapMode.LAZY is working with multiple EMF. I had the same problem with DEFERRED mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [the bean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/config/DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java) which is being erroneously re-registered, its implementation is simply doing a call to `beanFactory.getBeansOfType(Repository.class)`, which will force all repositories in the app context to be initialized on application startup, regardless of their EMF. So in theory it should be safe to have only one EMF marked as `DEFERRED` to get the desired behaviour.